# How to use JobScheduler on xamarin forms (android and UWP)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.uwp

I trying to make a utility that will send some scheduled random number of events, on random times on day.
I made the array of "times" that the events will be executed, but I don't know how to read that array and send to a method.

On following code the controls I use are:
TotalJobsPerDay = Entry control &
EndTime = TimePicker control.

```
private void BtnStart_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    TimeSpan start = TimeSpan.FromHours(7);
    TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.FromHours(int.Parse(EndTime.Time.ToString().Substring(0, EndTime.Time.ToString().IndexOf(':'))));
    int maxMinutes = (int)((end - start).TotalMinutes);

    TimeSpan[] t = new TimeSpan[int.Parse(TotalJobsPerDay.Text)];

    for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; ++i)
    {
        int minutes = random.Next(maxMinutes);
        t[i] = start.Add(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(minutes));
    }
    var events = t.OrderBy(x => x.Hours).ToList();
    //Read the array and on containing times doSomething() within the day...
}
```

I expect the utility to work on Android and UWP systems. 
(I'm very sorry about my bad English)

Comment: Do you want to used `JobScheduler` in android like this link https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/replacing-services-jobs-android-oreo-8-0/. `JobScheduler` is meant for performing tasks when the OS wants to. This is used to conserve battery life and run multiple jobs from multiple apps at the same time in android, Or you want to execute a method at some time of the day? If so, ` Alarm Manager ` is a good choice in android. I am not familar with UWP. I cannot give advice about UWP